# is there a lambda function that cannot be a method reference

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, method-reference

in a lecture I gave at my company I suggested converting any complex lambda to a method reference (more readable and better debug and testing) and was asked if it is always possible.

I searched and could not find a lambda that cannot be replaced with method reference.

am I right? (lambda can always be replaced with method reference)

Comment: Sorry, question makes no sense for me. Could you explain with maybe a code sample?

Comment: If the lambda is capturing local variables, it cannot be converted to a method reference.

Comment: the question is - in java 8, is there a type of lambda expression that cannot be refactored as a method reference?
e.g. -personList.forEach(x->System.out.println(x.getLaptop().getBrand())) could be replaced with personList.forEach(x->System.out.println(ThisClass::printLaptopBrabd)

Comment: Misha can you give an example?

Comment: `int x = 1; numberList.replaceAll(n -> n + x);`  Also, your code will not compile.  You cannot use a method reference as argument to `S.o.println`.

Comment: @Misha thanks for the exmaple now I get it. as for my code its a typo the "x->sout" should have been deleted...
if you will post your comment as answer I will accept it.

Comment: @Tunaki did you downvote my question? if so why?

Comment: @TalJoffe - 1) It is none of your business if Tunaki down-voted your question.  2) If he did, then his comment is a plausible explanation why.  He thinks your question needs an example so that people can understand it. (I don't agree, but he is entitled to his opinion and he is entitled to downvote.  Get over it!)

Comment: @StephenC I just thought it would be nicer to let me re-edit the question before downvoting... I'm new here and trying to build my rep so I can be more active.. anyway I get what you are saying

Comment: @Tal Joffe: just do your re-edit and perhaps, whoever downvoted, will retract the downvote. Or your then-better question receives more upvotes. In either case, Stephen is right, don’t waste time thinking too long about a single downvote…

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Method reference cannot capture variables.  So a capturing lambda cannot be directly converted to a method reference.  For example,

```
int x = 1;
numbers.replaceAll(n -> n + x);
```

In some cases, if only one variable is captured, it might be possible to convert lambda to a method reference on the captured variable.  For example,

```
String greeting = "Hello, ";

people.replaceAll(name -> greeting + name);
```

Can be converted to method reference as

```
people.replaceAll(greeting::concat);
```